# Is there a way to sort and remove duplicates from a list in an easier way?

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the duplicates from a list. First tried to do so by comparing the elements of 2 lists but i am no satisfied with this method. Is there an easier way?

```
list1 = [a, b, b, c, c, d,]
list2 = [b, c]
for list1 in list2:
   list.append(list.remove())
return list
```

But this way i remove all of the members that are in list1 and list2 and i want to remove only the duplicates.

Comment: Please give us input in correct format. Are `a`, `b`,.. python variables or string literals?

Comment: What does list2 have to do with removing duplicates from list1? Also, does removing duplicates mean `[a,d]` or `[a,b,c,d]`?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
readmelist.sort()
readmelist = list(dict.fromkeys(readmelist))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a new list called 'list' that contains no duplicat items.
Also note that you have an extra , at the end of list1 which will cause errors and that a is read as a variable, to read it as a string use 'a'.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['b', 'c']
list = []
for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        list.append(i)
print(list)
```

Comment: The extra comma at the end of the OPs list is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

to the issue removing duplicates:

`list1=list(set(list1))`

But I honestly don't know what you want with your second list.
If you want to remove all items which are in the second list from list one use a for loop. If you want to remove all items which are in the second list and several times in the first one, you should use a for loop with a counter and only remove the entry if counter >=1.
For the last case even better would be using a mask and then remove the values (you do not have to loop over your list over and over this way).

Maybe you want something like

```
list_out= list( set(list1) - set(list2))
```

EDIT: just saw this is a duplicate question [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists?rq=1) and therefore should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way that I have found so far is using dictionary.

`list1 = [a, b, b, c, c, d,]
    list1 = list(dict.fromkeys(list1))`

dict.fromkeys(object) creates a dictionary with keys but no values.

Since a dictionary can only have unique keys, duplicates are automatically removed.

We then cast the dictionary into a list using list('Dictionary_Here')

Hope this helps.